JPA Subquery return object and use on query multiselect
I'm have a java spring application that use a criteria query. The query has a multiselect and one of the values is a subquery that bring an complete entity. The application work on original enviroment where we create it but we try to run in a new environment and updated some libs and now doesn't work.
Example of case
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    private Long id;
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataResultQuery {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private Address firstAddress;
    private Address lastAddress;
}

public class Example {

    public DataResultQuery getData(Long id) {
        var builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var query = builder.createQuery(DataResultQuery.class);

        var user = query.from(User.class);
        var address = user.join(User_.addresses);

        var firstAddress = getSubquery(address);
        var lastAddress = getSubquery(address);

        query.multiselect(
                user.get(User_.name),
                user.get(User_.lastName),
                firstAddress.getSelection(),
                lastAddress.getSelection()
        );

        query.where(); //Predicates

        var typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);

        return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    }

    private Subquery<Address> getSubquery(Join<?, Address> address) {
        var builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var query = builder.createQuery(Address.class);
        var subquery = query.subquery(Address.class);

        var address = subquery.from(Address.class);

        subquery.select(address);

        subquery.where(); //Predicates

        return subquery;
    }
}

And return something like this when i try to execute the query
Cannot instantiate class 'com.package.example.result_queries.DataResultQuery' (it has no constructor with signature
I tried search something about but i did not found anything and tried to create the full constructor manually

Try to add @NoArgConstructor as well then see how it goes

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This solution didn't work form me
